# Generate api key for google map while publishing the app

Tags: android

I am trying to do dis more than an hour but unable to find the apt solution.
My app is ready, so i am trying to export it using signed application option in eclipse IDE.
the apk file is getting generated
But the problem is the google map inside map whose API Key was generated using default debug keystore is not working.
So i need to create a new API key by creating a new keystore.
How does it go?
please explain

Comment: no help... the app is working fine on other mobile only the map doesnt get opened

Comment: Thank u all. found out the solution. I wasnt changing the api key in class files . i know silly mistake but that was d issue

Answer (score 1):

using your new keystore find the SHA1 key from eclipse and create a new API key for google map.

Comment: I did it..but still it isnt working on my colleagues mobile.. but only on my mobile. Is it because it is using the api key associated with the debug certificate of my app?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need another API key anymore, you just have to add the SHA1 finger print of the keystore you use for creating the signed APK to the existing API key:

Supposing you have created your API key in the API Console, go there again and click the 'Edit allowed Android Applications' button below your already existing API Key. 
There, add a new line with the SHA1 finger print of the keystore you used to create the signed APK and the package name of your app (it's explained anyways when you hit that button) and you're done.

Comment: can u please share the steps to do it in Eclipse IDE

Comment: i tried it.. but no use :(... the app is getting hanged and shutting down

Comment: Did you create the original API key in the API console?

Answer (score 1):

The Eclipse debug key for signing your application can be found in the userhome/.android/debug.keystore file.

To create the SHA-1 for your debug keystore you use the keytool command from your JDK installation pointing to the debug.keystore file.

```
keytool -list -v -alias androiddebugkey \
-keystore <path_to_debug_keystore>debug.keystore \
-storepass android -keypass android
```

Copy the SHA-1 output, as you need this later.

Answer (score 0):

In the console, You need to create a new Android key in pulbic api acccess.

You need to get the SHA1 
keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command to get SHA-1 to get Api-Key. Here's  [link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start)

```
keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_name
```

If you don't want to regenerate or re assign the key, then go to Google APi console and Enable the Api-Key for all application either signed or unsigned